# SailsJS User Profiles Routing

Tags: node.js, authentication, sails.js, waterline

I'm developing an application in Sails.js, where I have two kinds of users; ordinary users (who should be able to view their own profile), and administrators (who should be able to view/edit/delete every users' profile). For authentication, I've followed [this example](https://github.com/sails101/basic-login).

Currently, I'm using the blueprints to directly access this information via a view `/views/user/show/userID`, e.g. `/views/user/show/ + user.id`, where the view displays information based on the userID provided (e.g. `<%= user.name %>`. Currently, anyone can access any profile due to this.

I need to limit access so that a "regular" user only has access to his/her own profile, as well as not be able to edit/delete other users.

I'm not sure how exactly to do this, and I've tried using custom routes, without success.

Any suggestion/answer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [policy](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies) (i.e. `isAdmin.js`) where you check if the user has an "administrator" user role and if not you can return a "forbidden" error code.

Then in your `config/policies.js` you can associate the specific policy `isAdmin.js` to your api method.

Another valid approach could be defining a `isProfileOwner.js` policy where you check if the user that submitted the request is the owner of the profile on which he wants to operate

Hope this could help you

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look into that :)